# Reconstructing object tree from joined query

Tags: scala, slick

Let's assume I have following DB model (not a real case so please forgive me the utter silliness of this example):

[image]

I want to fetch joined result from db in such a way that I could compose a tree of these object starting from `Faculty` element.

Thus I would have following case classes:

```
  case class StudentWithGrades(student: Student, grades: Seq[Grade])
  case class GroupWithStudents(group: Group, students: Seq[Student])
  case class FacultyWithGroups(faculty: Faculty, groups: Seq[Group])
```

and would like to reconstruct rows retrieved from the db in such way that I would at the end have simply a `Seq[FacultyWithGroups]`.

Is there any easier way than this:

```
  db.run (
    FacultyTable
      .join(GroupTable).on(_.id === _.facultyId)
      .join(StudentTable).on(_._2.id === _.groupId)
      .join(GradeTable).on(_._2.id === _.studentId)
      .result
      .map {
        _.groupBy { case (((faculty, group), student), _) =>
          (faculty, group, student)
        }
        .map { case ((faculty, group, student), groupped) =>
          (faculty, group, StudentWithGrades(student, groupped.map(_._2)))
        }
        .toSeq
        .groupBy { case (faculty, group, studentGrades) =>
          (faculty, group)
        }
        .map { case ((faculty, group), groupped) =>
          (faculty, GroupWithStudents(group, groupped.map(_._3)))
        }
        .toSeq
        .groupBy { case(faculty, group) =>
            faculty
        }
        .map { case(faculty, groupped) =>
          FacultyWithGroups(faculty, groupped.map(_.2))
        }
      }
  )
```

Although it is actually related to `Slick` (reconstructing object trees in a way similar to classic `ORM`s) it seems to me that it is basically more of a problem with clever processing of collections than `Slick` itself.